# How to localize Woocommerce weight

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, in settings of Woocommerce weight and other metric system in Russian language.
But in product page for example it still in English (g - gramm).
I have copied file in to my theme: `/wp-content/themes/my_theme/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php`
What should I do in this file to display right Weight metric system in Russian language? This code did not help:

```
<td class="product_weight"><?php echo wc_format_localized_decimal( $product->get_weight() ) . ' ' . __(esc_attr( get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ) ), 'woocommerce'); ?></td>
```

Code of `/product-attributes.php`:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
    return;
}
?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check what the actual value of `woocommerce_weight_unit` is, and then translate it within the `woocommerce` domain, with the help of whatever localization plugin you are using?

Comment: Done. Just added code in theme's functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done, just posted this code in theme's functions.php

```
function localize_weight_units($weight) {
    return str_replace('g', 'г', $weight);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_format_weight', 'localize_weight_units');
```